library "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.15" does not run with the "npx expo start --tunnel" command inside Docker
I'm using the maps lib in an optimized routes application. I run the application inside a docker container, and access the application from my phone with the QR code, but this error is returning me. Apparently the lib uses some things that I'm not aware of in native Android that I can't access with the type of expo connection I'm using. See the image:

At least I believe this is the description of the problem, I saw the development of this part already underway and I don't have much expertise with this lib.
I tried to get a more updated version of the lib to see if it solved it, but it didn't. I'm using the version: "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.0.15"
